# Cyclic combination of two list of different length

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have two list:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
```

and I want to make the list:

```
list3 = [('1','a'),('2','b'),('3','c'),('4','a'),('5','b')]
```

In other words, do a cyclic combination between them. So, my question is: Which is the more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
>>> zip(list2, cycle(list1))
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'a'), ('5', 'b')]
```

As some have mentioned in the comments, if you want to cycle both lists and take the first n elements you can do that with,

```
>>> from itertools import islice, izip
>>> list(islice(izip(cycle(list2), cycle(list1)), 5))
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'a'), ('5', 'b')]
```

Comment: Waw! cycle is amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Volatility: but in that case, wouldn't the result go on forever?

Comment: @LarsH True, hadn't though of that.

Comment: @Volatility: you had a good point, and I think you *do* need to take the cycle of both, but then just take the first `n` elements of the result of `zip()`, where `n` is the max of the lengths of list1 and list2. I'm assuming `zip()` returns an iterator.

Comment: @LarsH you would probably use `izip` and `islice` for that

Comment: @Volatility: I think you should post an answer. :-) My python is rusty.

Comment: And of course, in Python 3.x `zip` is an iterator and there is no `izip` so you would have to make the necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach: A generator that continues the cyclic combination forever:

```
def cc(l1, l2):
  i=0
  c1 = len(l1)
  c2 = len(l2)
  while True:
    yield (l1[i % c1], l2[i % c2])
    i += 1
```

The literal answer to your question is then:

```
x=cc(list2, list1)
[next(x) for i in range(max(len(list1), len(list2)))]
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'a'), ('5', 'b')]
```

But you now have a flexible foundation from which to derive all sorts of other interesting bits.